# How to use ChosenInlineResultHandler in Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I try use [python-telegram-bot](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I do not understand how to handle InlineKeyboardButton correctly.

```
def start(bot, update):

    currencies = [currency for currency in API().get_currencies()]    

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("{}".format(c), callback_data='{}'.format(c))] for c in currencies]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Select the currency you want to exchange:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
```

Now, I need to process the selection by passing it to another function with the help of `ChosenInlineResultHandler`, but I do not understand how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You are using Inline Buttons and the query coming back is simply `CallbackQuery` but not `InlineQuery`, yes the names are a bit confusing by the Telegram Bot API.

You can use [`telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler`](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html) to catch the queries upon buttons pressed.

```
def button_callback(bot, update):
    # data is the callback_data where you declared in the buttons
    query = update.callback_query.data
    if query == "something":
        # do something here

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_callback))
```

This is a minimal example of how to catch the buttons' data. You can check [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py) for a complete example.